# ANE Packaging with IOS11

Tags: ios, air, ane

i have devloped an ANE that connects to a bluetooth printer in order to print ,this ane was working perfectly  until IOS 11 has been publish
now what i see in the log is that the printer connects but cant print 
i updated the xCode to support ios 11 and updates the **air to 27** and compiled the new ane and the swc also compiled in air 27

now when i try to publish the app i got this msg "
Error occurred while packaging the application:

> Error: META-INF/ANE/iPhone-ARM/libCoreMobileAPI.a,
>   META-INF/ANE/iPhone-ARM/libZebraChecker.a are required to have
>   universal iOS libraries. Please contact the ANE developer(s) to get
>   the same."

This ANE works only for IOS

iam sure that i have chosen universal iOS when i build the .a file
anyone has solution or can give me hints what to do
thanks

Descriptor XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<extension xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/27.0">
    <id>BlCheck.ZebraAneBLCheck</id>
    <versionNumber>1.0.0</versionNumber>
    <platforms>

        <platform name="iPhone-ARM">
        <applicationDeployment>
            <nativeLibrary>libZebraChecker.a</nativeLibrary>
            <initializer>cubecomDoitflashZebraPrinterExtensionInitializer</initializer>
            <finalizer>cubecomDoitflashZebraPrinterExtensionFinalizer</finalizer>
        </applicationDeployment>
        </platform>

        <platform name="default">
            <applicationDeployment/>
        </platform>

    </platforms>
</extension>
```

Answer (score 0):

In Architectures settings of your target make sure you have your settings as below. Important parts are the "Valid Architectures" and the "Build Active Architecture Only" settings.

[image]

If that doesn't work make sure that you are using the correct `.a` file. You can run the following command on the .a file:

```
file libZebraChecker.a
```

It should output something like the following if it is a universal binary:

```
libZebraChecker.a: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [arm_v7: current ar archive] [arm64: current ar archive]
libZebraChecker.a (for architecture armv7): current ar archive
libZebraChecker.a (for architecture arm64): current ar archive
```

Comment: I have the same settings above and i did the file libZebraChecker.a  and i got the same answer u show  libZebraChecker.a: Mach-O universal binary with 2 architectures: [arm_v7: current ar archive] [arm64: current ar archive]
libZebraChecker.a (for architecture armv7): current ar archive
libZebraChecker.a (for architecture arm64): current ar archive  But still the same error